# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'populate')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

here i am taking ref from category and sub category field from their database and want to populate the name of category and sub category but getting this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'populate')"

```
    this.products.findOne({ _id: req.query.productId }, { createdAt: 0, updatedAt: 0, isActive: 0, isDeleted: 0, __v: 0 })
        .exec(function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                callback(error);
            }
            if (data && data.length == 0) {
                return callback(false, common.errorMsg("NO Details FOUND"));
            } else {
                // return callback(false, common.successMsg("product list", data));
                data=data.map(function(item){
                    return {
                        productId: item._id,
                    productName: item.productName,
                    storeName: item.createdBy.fullName,
                    categoryName:item.category.name,
                    subCategoryName:item.subCategory.name,
                    image: item.fabricType[0].style[0].images[0],
                    price: item.price
                    }
                })
            }
            return callback(false, common.successMsg("product", data));
        }).populate('createdBy').populate('category').populate('subCategory').lean()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `exec` method returns a promise, so after that, you can't call the `populate` function. try this code:

```
this.products
   .findOne(
       { _id: req.query.productId },
       { createdAt: 0, updatedAt: 0, isActive: 0, isDeleted: 0, __v: 0 },
   )
   .populate('createdBy')
   .populate('category')
   .populate('subCategory')
   .lean()
   .exec(function (error, data) {
       // ...
   })
```

Comment: do you know why .map function giving error its says .map function is not defined

Comment: Because the `findOne` method returns a **document**, not an **array**

Comment: you just write `if (!data._id) { // not found message } else { // return the data }`

Comment: nice thanks i just heard for this so i remember it from now